# Extract environment variables from grep search

Tags: grep, environment-variables

I'd like to generate some `.env.example` files for a dozen of projects.

In order to be smart and avoid tedious copy/pasting I thought about using the `grep` command.

How can I get from :

```
➜  app-service git:(chore/adding-env-example) ✗ c;grep -r "process\.env\." --exclude-d
ir=node_modules
./src/config/config_prod.js:    level: process.env.LOG_LEVEL || 'error'
./src/config/config_prod.js:      bypassToken: process.env.BYPASS_TOKEN || null
./src/config/config.js:  port: process.env.APP_PORT || 3000,
./src/config/config.js:  frontUrl: process.env.FRONT_URL,
./src/config/config.js:      launchAppTopic: process.env.AWS_SNS_LAUNCH_APP_ARN
...
```

to

```
LOG_LEVEL=
BYPASS_TOKEN=
APP_PORT=
FRONT_URL=
AWS_SNS_LAUNCH_APP_ARN=
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Retrieving the Environment Variables:

```
 grep -oP "(?<=\.)[[:upper:]_]*(?=[ ,]*)"
```

##### Results:

```
LOG_LEVEL
BYPASS_TOKEN
APP_PORT
FRONT_URL
AWS_SNS_LAUNCH_APP_ARN
```

#### Retrieving the Environment Variables and adding `=`

```
sed -r -n  's|^.*\.([[:upper:]_]+).*$|\1=|p'
```

##### Results:

```
LOG_LEVEL=
BYPASS_TOKEN=
APP_PORT=
FRONT_URL=
AWS_SNS_LAUNCH_APP_ARN=
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find all occurrences of an uppercase letter followed by uppercase letters and/or underscores, and then an `=`, and only if it is a word in itself:

```
grep -o -P '\b[A-Z][A-Z_]*='
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be working. Is it specific to Linux ?

`➜  app-service git:(chore/adding-env-example) ✗ c;grep -r "process\.env\." --exclude-dir=node_modules | grep -o -P '\b[A-Z][A-Z_]*='
grep: invalid option -- P
usage: grep [-abcdDEFGHhIiJLlMmnOopqRSsUVvwXxZz] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
 [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
 [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
 [--null] [pattern] [file ...]`

Comment: You'll have to look at your `grep` man page to see if `-P` for Perl regular expressions is supported. If not, then we'll need to do something else.  But that's the basics of what you need to do.